# ruby rails caching

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, caching, sdk

I am using this code insite my controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

    cache_expire = 60*60*24*365
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "public"
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=#{cache_expire}"
    response.headers["Expires"] = Time.at(Time.now.to_i + cache_expire).strftime("%D, %d %M % Y %H:%i:%s")
    render :layout => "application", 
           :inline => "<script src='//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>"
```

The caching is working properly, and my webapp does support subdomains.

When I browse to mysubdomain.something.com it gives me an "Routing Error"

> undefined local variable or method `response' for ProjectsController:Class

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is supposed to be inside of some method.

```
def index
  cache_expire = 60*60*24*365
  response.headers["Pragma"] = "public"
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=#{cache_expire}"
  response.headers["Expires"] = Time.at(Time.now.to_i + cache_expire).strftime("%D, %d %M % Y %H:%i:%s")
  render :layout => "application", 
         :inline => "<script src='//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>"
end
```

`response` doesn't exist or make sense at class level.